# Cartan matrices of combinatorial algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, matrices

Call a quiver algebra $A=kQ/I$ with connected acyclic $Q$ **combinatorial** when the following two conditions are satisfied:

> 1. For any two points $i,j$ in the quiver of $A$ there is at most one path from $i$ to $j$ (modulo $I$ of course). Or equivalently: For any two indecomposable projective $A$-modules $P$ and $U$ we have $dim(Hom_A(P,U)) \leq 1$.

> 2. For any point $i$ in the quiver there starts (ends) a unique longest path at $i$ (modulo $I$ of course). Or equivalently: $A$ is QF-2, that means that the socle of any indecomposable projective right (left) $A$-module is simple.

For example incidence algebras of bounded posets ($Q$ is here just the Hasse quiver) are combinatorial as well as linear Nakayama algebras that correspond to Dyck paths. But there are other examples like glueing such a linear Nakayama algebras to the end of the Hasse quiver of a bounded poset.

> Question 1: Do you know other algebras that come from combinatorics and are combinatorial?

The **Cartan matrix** $C_A$ of $A$ is defined as the matrix $C$ with entries $c_{i,j}=$ number of paths starting at $j$ and ending at $i$, or equivalently $c_{i,j}=dim(Hom_A(e_iA,e_jA))=dim(e_j Ae_i)$ where $e_iA$ are the indecomposable projective $A$-modules.

The points of $Q$ of a combinatorial algebra $A$ can be ordered so that $C_A$ is an upper triangular 0-1 matrix with diagonal entries all equal to one.

Of course the Cartan matrix depends on the choice of a numbering of the vertices and is only unique up to a permutation, and we identify two Cartan matrices as equivalent when they coincide up to such a permutation.

> Question 2: Are two combinatorial algebra $A_1$ and $A_2$ isomorphic if and only if their Cartan matrices are equivalent?

This is not true for algebras $A$ as above that just satisfy condition 1., for example take $A_1$ to be a linear oriented type Dynkin type $\mathcal{A}_n$ path algebra and $A_2$ the radical square zero algebra with arrows $1 \to 2$, $1 \to 3$, $1 \to 4$, $2 \to 3$, $2 \to 4$, $3 \to 4$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the same Cartan matrix, but $A_2$ does not satisfy condition 2.

A positive answer might lead to a linear algebraic classification of combinatorial algebras in terms of their Cartan matrices.

So, in case question 2 has a positive answer can one give conditions on a given upper triangular 0-1 matrix with entries only 1 on the diagonal to characterise whether it is the Cartan matrix of a combinatorial algebra?

For example the following matrix is also an upper triangular 0-1 matrix with entries only 1 on the diagonal, but does not correspond to a combinatorial algebra.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

But the following matrix is the Cartan matrix of the incidence algebra of the Boolean lattice and thus comes from a combinatorial algebra:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

> Question 3: When is a given upper triangular 0-1 matrix with entries only 1 on the diagonal the Cartan matrix of a combinatorial algebra? I would think there is a nice criterion to translate condition 2 into linear algebra if question 2 has a positive answer.